# Magento 2 - Add custom js in admin product edit

Tags: magento2, product, xml, admin-panel

I want to add **custom js** in **product edit page** (Admin)

Is it ok to add it in some **xml** or is there any other way to do it?

If it is xml, which XML do I need to work on?

Comment: Yes you need to add in XML file.

Comment: can you help me with the code? which xml do I need to edit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some efforts on this and I think this solution is much better and easy to implement

Add XML file in a custom module

```
app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_edit.xml
```

File code will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Naheed_HomeProductsGrid::js/custom_product_edit.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Add new js file in module view directory

```
app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\web\js\custom_product_edit.js
```

File code will be:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //Custom js here
    });
});
```

And if you want to run js after all ajax call complete then use `jQuery(document).ajaxStop()`
Code will be like this:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            //Custom js here
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes you can add but without defining the path and it's dependencies in require-config.js is an bad practice and of course there will be jquery conflict without defining dependency. Show me any core modules which add js without require-config.js. 
Please have a look at it
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Answer (score 2):

You can add your custom js file in the layout file : `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Catalog::js/customJsFile.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

After that create your `customJsFile.js` file in the `web/js` folder.

Comment: Your solution will work, but editing vendor file is not a good way of development. Thanks anyway for taking time in answering my question. +1

Comment: @ShoaibMunir, yes definitely we should not edit core files, You can create your own module and create the above xml file there.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks. I gave you +1 on your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add requireconfig-js to load your customjs in any page of magento.

Full description in below link

[Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html)